# Breeze: Required Validator not in the metadata when using a NHibernate context provider

Tags: breeze

We've noticed that the metadata generated for the following model:

```
    [Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
```

looks like this

```
 {
 nameOnServer: "Title",
 dataType: "String",
 isNullable: true
 },
```

in other words, the Required validator is not added.

Is this because NH does not use data annotation. Is this something that is not implemented or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because NH does not use Data Annotations.  The metadata is built using NHibernate's [metadata api](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#manipulatingdata-metadata), which gets info from .hbm.xml files, mapping-by-code, or fluent configuration.  It would be possible to inspect the model classes for annotations during the metadata generation process, but it's not something we're working on.  It would also be possible to post-process the metadata structure after it is created (but before it is serialized to JSON), and add the extra metadata hints then.

Separately, we have an (admittedly crude) example of using Data Annotations for server-side validation during the SaveChanges process.  There's a [DataAnnotationsValidator](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.ContextProvider/DataAnnotationsValidator.cs) class, which you would use in your `BeforeSaveEntities` method, like this:

```
    protected override Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> BeforeSaveEntities(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap) {
      var validator = new DataAnnotationsValidator(this);
      validator.ValidateEntities(saveMap, true);

      return base.BeforeSaveEntities(saveMap);
    }
```

I know that isn't what you had in mind (because it doesn't help your client-side validation at all), but it's there if you need it.

Hope this helps.